# Spring Boot @Autowired property null

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, autowired

Decided to venture into Spring Boot and have hit a big snag with @Autowired property returning null.  There are many solutions here I've tried but none has worked on my particular case.

To state, the common theme, @Autowired in my Application.java works fine but not in my Controller. (@Autowired works here)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JackandjasonApplication implements ApplicationRunner{

private final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(JackandjasonApplication.class);

@Autowired
JackAndJasonPDFParser parser;

@Value("${remote.schedule.file}")
private String file;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(JackandjasonApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Processing Schedule file: " + file);
    parser.parse(file);  // <--- This works fine
}
```

}

Here are my steps:
1. In WebAppConfig.java, I registered a secondary servlet:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<com.jackandjason.route.planner.jackandjason.servlet.JackandjasonFileUploadServlet> getScheduleServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new com.jackandjason.route.planner.jackandjason.servlet.JackandjasonFileUploadServlet(), "/schedule/upload/file/*");
}
```

Also in WebAppConfig.java, I registered a Bean:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public JackAndJasonPDFParser getParser() {
    return new JackAndJasonPDFParser();
}
```

JackAndJasonPDFParser.java

```
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.jackandjason.route.planner.jackandjason"})
    @Service
    public class JackAndJasonPDFParser {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ScheduleRepository schedRepo;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JackAndJasonPDFParser.class);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    private List<Schedule> schedules;
    public List<Schedule> parse(String path) {
        List<Schedule> listOfSchedules = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
    }
}
```

In this new Controller, I @Autowired a parser variable - NULL occurs in here

```
   @Controller
   public class JackandjasonFileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Logger logger =  
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(JackandjasonFileUploadServlet.class);

    @Autowired
    private JackAndJasonPDFParser parser;

    private static final int MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = (1024 * 1024 * 2);
    private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = (1024 * 1024);

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //Check that we have a file upload request
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

        if(!isMultipart) {
            return;
        }

        //Create a factory for disk-based file items
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        //Set the size threshold for writing file directly to the server disk.
        factory.setSizeThreshold(MAX_MEMORY_SIZE);

        //Set the directory used to temporarily store files larger than the threshold. I use the Java temp directory
        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

        String dailySchedDir = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "daily_schedule";

        //Create a file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        //Set the overall request size limit
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

        try {
            //Parse the request
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));
            logger.info("List of Items: " + gson.toJson(items));
            Iterator<FileItem> itr = items.iterator();
            String filePath = new String();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = itr.next();
                if(!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    filePath = dailySchedDir + File.separator + fileName;
                    File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);
                    logger.info("Uploading " + filePath);
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
                }
            }
            //Parse the file
            List<Schedule> listOfSchedules = parser.parse(filePath);    // <---- NULL 
            if(listOfSchedules != null) {
                logger.info(filePath + " successfully parsed");
            } else {
                logger.error("An error occurred while parsing " + filePath);
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

What did I miss in my setup/configuration?  Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the fully source code of the WebAppConfig.java , JackAndJasonPDFParser.java and controller with relevant package declaration?

Comment: Why you use Controller annotation with Servlet class? Controller annotation typically used in combination with annotated handler methods based on the
RequestMapping annotation.

Comment: Add the `com.jackandjason.route.planner.jackandjason.servlet.JackandjasonFileUploadServlet` as a bean instead of creating a new instance yourself inside the  method.